# Tensorflow catch singular matrix error (tf.matrix_solve)

Tags: tensorflow, exception

I have a scenario where I can obtain a closed-form solution, which involves tf.matrix_solve. Tensorflow is smart enough to check if the matrix is singular and throws an exception if that's the case. How can I handle this? The example below does not work.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

def closed_form_solution(A,b):
    try:
        x = tf.matrix_solve(A, b)
    except Exception, e:
        x = tf.convert_to_tensor([[np.nan]] * 2)
    return x

# A and b are actually filled at each training step,
A = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[1., 1.], [2., 2.]]))
b = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array([[0.], [1.]]))
x = closed_form_solution(A,b)
x.eval()  # Throws InvalidArgumentError
```

The following function seems to work most of the time, but since I don't catch anything it could still kill my training.

```
def closed_form_solution(A,b):
    return tf.cond(tf.less_equal(tf.abs(tf.matrix_determinant(A)), 1e-5),
                   lambda : tf.convert_to_tensor([[np.nan]] * 2, dtype=tf.float64),
                   lambda : tf.matrix_solve(A, b))
```

Is there a better solution to avoid the exception?

Comment: In what way does it not work? You could do a `try...except...` and handle the error on the `except` clause. You say if it is possible to "avoid" the exception, but if your matrix does not have inverse then you *will* be getting that error, you can only handle it in that case. If you elaborate more I could help you better.

Comment: My wording was not optimal. _Avoiding_ the exception is impossible if I can't control the matrix, but I want to _handle_ the exception. So if the matrix is singular return nan and proceed with the next iteration. At the moment the exception stops the program.

Comment: Ok, I get you better now. Could you elaborate more on what you mean by "next iteration"? I assume you are executing `x.eval()` several times and when you get `InvalidArgumentError` it stops the whole program, is that true?

Comment: Could you also add the stack trace you get when the error appears?

Comment: No in-graph exception handling in the near future https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10332